# Angular Library Modules export components, services and others from module

Tags: angular, import, export, angular-module, angular-library

I have created an Angular Library. In my Library I would it like it to be clean by having feature modules inside them:

**Example:**

```
Library
  NavigationModule
    NavigationSideBarComponent
    NavigationTopComponent
    Navigation Service
    etc

  GraphModule
    BarGraphComponent
    PieGraphComponent
```

My Navigation Module currently looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NavigationSidebarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatSidenavModule
  ],
  exports: [
    NavigationSidebarComponent
  ]
})
export class NavigationModule { }
```

My Library Module currently looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [LibraryComponent],
    imports: [
      NavigationModule
    ],
    exports: [
      LibraryComponent
      //NavigationSidebarComponent  <-- Did not work
    ]
 })
 export class LibraryModule { }
```

Most tutorials I am finding is using a library with only components in them and nothing else such as modules. The tutorials I do find using modules in a library do not show how to export pieces.

Essentially I want to import this Library into any application and be able to call `NavigationSidebarComponent` or any other component from a module in the library or service.

I will keep looking into this on my end.

Comment: I have never built and published a library, but I've noticed that some UI vendors publish individual modules to npm separately. Here's an example of a 3rd party vendor's Dropdown components module. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns

Comment: Thanks Keenan, ya I am thinking maybe this is not possible. Only the ones that import the module have access to their components, etc. I was hoping to do it like this because then I could have one library with each module being a feature

Comment: It is starting to look like I need to make a library for each which would be terrible to manage. Or put all components regardless of types like header, footer, tables, all in the library module.

Comment: My main thought though is Angular supports it so I would assume it is dooable

Comment: If you have a dependency of one module on another (using the BarGraphComponent in your NavigationTopComponent implementation for example), that might be okay. As long as the dependency is 1-way.

Comment: Look at the dependencies that the @progress kendo grid has: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/#toc-dependencies

And actually, it looks like npm support peer dependencies, so forget my 1-way comment.

Comment: So the navigation and graph are seperate modules. I want the appModule importing the library to be able to use both. I will take a look

Comment: I could be wrong but I think there's is different. I think theirs is the kendo is using all these different modules for itself. What I am trying to do is have many different modules in a library and then import that library to an app and be able to call components and services for both modules

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to export `NavigationModule` in the `LibraryModule`, not `NavigationSidebarComponent`

Comment: Thanks the module approach I believe is best for a library.

Answer (score 5):

I think you don't need a top level "Library module" at all.  Look at [the source tree for `@angular/material`](https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/material): I think they used to have a `material.module` and got rid of it, and now the root only has a completely empty `index.ts`.  Each component has its own module, and modules like [the one for MatAutocomplete](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/autocomplete/autocomplete-module.ts) import modules that they depend on (like `MatOptionModule`) and re-export them.

I've been converting a project of mine to a similar model, and doing research to figure out the current best practices for module structure.  I believe Material converted from a "monolithic library" approach, where you were encouraged to `import { MatAutocompleteModule } from "@angular/material"` to one module per component (or group of related components), because this approach allows you to distribute the library as a single package, but still benefit from tree-shaking, so only the modules that are actually used will be included in your build.