# How can I import a feature module from an custom Angular library?

Tags: angular, typescript

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54012806/angular-library-modules-export-components-services-and-others-from-module) I built a **custom Angular library** (with *Angular CLI 7.2.0*) with multiple **feature** modules:

```
MyLibraryModule
  FeatureModule1
    SomeComponent1
  FeatureModule2
    SomeComponent2
```

I want to import only one **feature** module into my main application, like we can do with Angular Material modules (`import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material';`):

```js
import { FeatureModule1 } from 'my-library';
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    FeatureModule1,
  ]
})
...
```

This results in the following error (during building the main project):

```
ERROR in : Unexpected value 'FeatureModule1 in ./node_modules/my-library/my-library.d.ts'
imported by the module 'AppModule in ./src/app/app.module.ts'.
Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

When I import the library module (`import { MyLibraryModule } from 'my-library';`) into my main application, everything works.

**my-library.module.ts** looks like this:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { FeatureModule1 } from './feature-module-1/feature-module-1.module';
import { FeatureModule2 } from './feature-module-2/feature-module-2.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ FeatureModule1, FeatureModule2 ],
  exports: [ FeatureModule1, FeatureModule2 ],
})
export class MyLibraryModule{ }
```

My `public_api.ts` exports all modules.

I think it has something to do with packaging process, because in my test project (which is in the same folder as the library) this works without any problems.

I already tried to adapt the [building process](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/tsconfig-build.json) from `@angular/material` but it seems, they are doing it a bit different then the *official* way.

Comment: You could take a look at how [ngx-bootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap) does it.

Comment: Thanks for this hint @Seiyria. Altough it didn't helped me with finding the solution directly, it pointed me at the correct direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that I used [barrel files](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/barrel.html) in my feature modules (`index.ts`) that I imported in my `public_api.ts` like this:

```
import * from './feature-module-1';
```

But as described [here](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/720), you have to point directly at the barrel file. Otherwise the `.d.ts` file for the package does not contain all exports. So the following line in my `public_api.ts` fixed the problem:

```
import * from './feature-module-1/index';
```

Comment: As a note for others, this issue manifested for me during application AOT builds only with the error: `Unexpected value 'MyModule' [...] Please add a @NgModule annotation.` Adding `/index` to imports in the library fixed it. Thanks!