# Load one module of angular library

Tags: angular, angular-library

With the following command I generated a library named (`cac-common`)

```
ng generate library cac-common
```

In this library I have 2 modules:

```
cac-common-utility (ng generate module cac-common-utility  --project=cac-common)

cac-common-security (ng generate module cac-common-security  --project=cac-common)
```

When I want to use the `cac-common-security` module I have to import it in any module as below:

```
import { CacCommonSecurityModule } from 'cac-common';

...
imports:[ CacCommonSecurityModule ]
...
```

My question are:

**1- the import above load the whole cac-common library or load only cac-common-security module ?**

**2- why I can not import the cac-common-security module like the following ?**

```
import { CacCommonSecurityModule } from 'cac-common/lib/cac-common-security/cac-common-security.module';
```

Comment: Can you update your 2 follow up questions? I am a bit confused on what you are asking. As well as for those can you supply a brief example? Thanks

Comment: When you get a chance to make those updates I will take another look. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You Can use Library by Importing its modules.

Or importing a name that wrap and export all the modules in it.

If you import modules via relative path of its directory, the source of library always must  be available. if you import by exported name, you can easily install it everywhere you want.

Comment: thanks , your answer is related to my second question .  What is the answer of my first question ?

Comment: Import Module from package or library  just import the module with dependency that set inside the module not anything more

Comment: if that is the case , why in the earlier version of Angular Material if we wanted to use button we  imported button like :  ``import {MatButtonModule} from @angular/material`` but in the current version we can import like : ``import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button`` , It means there is a diffrence between them . based on your answer , there is no diffrence between  ``@angular/material/button`` and ``@angular/material``

Comment: for example if you want to use ngx-button : https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/buttons you have two options to import 1- ``import { ButtonsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/buttons'`` 2- ``import { ButtonsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';``
they recommended to use 1 . based on your answer , there is no difference between , so  why they recommended import ``1``

Comment: There is a big Different between import form modules seperately and import from barrels (group of exports) see this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/54257329/2126355