# angular library export components, classes, services etc

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-library

I have vary similar issue from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54012806/angular-library-modules-export-components-services-and-others-from-module) but solutions from it did not helped me.
So I'm trying to export componetns from my library to then extend components in my main app. Structure of my library is next

[image]

In my `pages.module.ts` I have

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TrailblazersComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    TrailblazersComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})

export class PagesModule {
}
```

in the `carol-lb-lib.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CarolLbLibComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PagesModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature(
      lbFeatureKey,
      LB_REDUCER_TOKEN,
    ),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([GlobalBoardEffects])
  ],
  exports: [
    CarolLbLibComponent,
    PagesModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: LB_REDUCER_TOKEN, useFactory: getReducers}
  ]
})
export class CarolLbLibModule {
}
```

As you see I exportes `PagesModule` as were suggested in topic above. But when I install my lib in main project and trying to extend my component like this

```
import {TrailblazersComponent} from 'carol-lb-lib/lib/pages/trailblazers/trailblazers.component';

...
export class TrailblazersPageComponent extends TrailblazersComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              store: Store<AppState>) {
    super(store);
  }
}
```

I have an error
`ERROR in ./src/app/modules/leaderboard/pages/trailblazers/trailblazers-page.component.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'carol-lb-lib/lib/pages/trailblazers/trailblazers.component' in '/home/dd/Desktop/repos/dashboard/src/app/modules/leaderboard/pages/trailblazers'`

Whats wrong with this implementation? How can I fix it and also make import in my components in the app shorter? Like `import {component} from 'my-lib/components'`

Also my public.api file contains

```
export * from './lib/carol-lb-lib.service';
export * from './lib/carol-lb-lib.component';
export * from './lib/carol-lb-lib.module';
export * from './lib/pages/pages.module';
```

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: You do import `carol-lb-lib.module.ts` in the module that declares `TrailblazersPageComponent`?

Comment: It's more likely to set a wrong path for the module.

Comment: @GunnarB. No, `carol-lb-lib.module.ts` is top level module that I importing in my app. I can't import it inside PagesModule

Comment: @AliSoltani no, I don't think so

Comment: Due to the error content: `ERROR in ./src/app/modules/...`. I couldn't see `modules` in your folders. I said that wrong path.

Comment: I didn't mean to import in PagesModule, but in, say AppModule if that is where you declare `TrailblazersPageComponent`. From you answer it sounds like you do that though.

Comment: Can you use `CarolLbLibComponent` in your app without error?

Comment: @GunnarB. yes. And if declare and export TrailblazersComponent in `carol-lb-lib.module.ts` I can use it without errors. But It is not a solution in my opinion. this is normal practice to use modules for different types of components. Am I right?